# marking text in Windows 7's command prompt

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

I use Windows 7's command prompt (cmd.exe) for various tasks.
In order to copy text from it, I right click and choose Mark, and then mark the text I want to copy.

Sometimes while doing this, the marking doesn't stick. The minute I release the left mouse button after marking the text, the marking disappears.

This has happened on every Windows 7 installation I've ever installed.

How do I solve this?

Comment: I think there is a mouse bug in W7, I find all kinds of weirdness using the mouse on every Installation of W7 I have used on different hardware, nothing serious but annoying as hell. Have not found a solution yet but Microsoft needs to for sure.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) and see if that fits your needs better.

> Console is a Windows console window enhancement. Console features include: multiple tabs, text editor-like text selection, different background types, alpha and color-key transparency, configurable font, different window styles

Comment: It says Win2K and XP, this works for W7? what about W7 64bit?

Comment: @Moab - According to [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/forums/forum/143117/topic/4035867?message=8976728) it does.

Comment: thanks, I tried it and at least at this point I don't find it intuitive. Even the help doesn't give you the basic mouse\keyboard shortcuts and functionality.